# Image-picker html form

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

I'm having issues using Image-picker http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/

Basically i have managed to display the images I want, but i would like to wrap it all in an html form calling another php script and providing that php script the value from the selected image

```
<form action="dosomething.php" method="get" >
<select id="selectImage" class="image-picker">
<option data-img-src="files/1.jpg" input type="text" name="img" value="1">1</option>
<option data-img-src="files/2.jpg" input type="text" name="img" value="2">2</option>
<option data-img-src="files/3.jpg" input type="text" name="img" value="3">3</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

When i click on the form submit action, i get pointed to dosomething.php but my values are never passed through get

Could anyone give me some insight?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you trying to retrieve the value? Show your code in "dosomething.php"

Comment: dosomething.php doesnt exist yet.. But i ran the code above and never saw any parameters passed through the url.
I would get those values using $_GET['img']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to name your select tag.

eg.

```
<select id="selectImage" class="image-picker" name="image">
```

then try to retrieve with `$_GET['image'];`